# How to determine if "object is IEnumerable" (C# syntax) in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've seen a lot of posts for how to do this in C#, but I'm working in VB and they don't work and I can't seem to get them to convert. Anyone know this? C# is something like:

```
if (x is IEnumerable)
{

}
```

I'm looking to see if an object passed to my function implements IEnumerable so I can treat it like a collection.

I've already tried "x Is IEnumerable" and VB won't allow it anywhere... it expects a type of IEnumerable, such as IEnumerable(Of String).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even better, use `TryCast`. [TryCast Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx)

```
Dim collection As IEnumerable = TryCast(x, IEnumerable)
If collection IsNot Nothing Then
   ' do something
End If
```

Comment: Yes, had to look it up myself.

Comment: I've tried this and I get "Too few type arguments to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(of T)'" error here... you can't just put IEnumerable in VB.net, it expects a type.

Comment: Did you import the System.Collections namespace? (or change IEnumerable to System.Collections.IEnumerable)

Comment: That is what it was... I didn't have System.Collections imported. That is odd that it doesn't suggest that... usually it will give you the option to import a namespace that you might need if there is an error, but it doesn't here. I guess that is because you would usually use it as IEnumerable(Of T).

Answer (score 8):

See the [TypeOf ... Is ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) operator:

```
If TypeOf obj Is IEnumerable Then
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get "Too few type arguments to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(of T)'" error here...

Comment: @BarryFranklin: That means you didn't import `System.Collections` to get the non-generic interface.

Comment: Lazily I rely on VS to suggest namespace imports if there is an error or conflict with what I'm trying to use and for some reason it doesn't suggest to import System.Collections here. I never even thought of just putting Systems.Collections.IEnumerable. Sometimes it is the simplest of things.

Answer (score 3):

The VB equivalent would be:

```
If TypeOf x Is IEnumerable Then
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get "Too few type arguments to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(of T)'" error here...

Comment: That would be a result of what namespaces the compiler looks in. You could either add `Imports System.Collections` to the top of your code file or change the if-statement to check for `System.Collections.IEnumerable` instead of just `IEnumerable`